# How do I grant access /dev/console to an executable?

Tags: linux, permissions, gcc, c

I've written a small C app to utilize the internal PC's speaker. To achieve this, I'm talking to the `/dev/console` which in turn makes a beep sound from the speaker.

However, my compiled executable only works if I run as `root`. I understand that I should add the user running the executable to the proper group, but I don't know and can't find out what groups have the required permissions.

Running the executable as the user I'm currently trying to run as (`apache`) gives me `Permission denied`.

Any help please?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You control access to a device the same way you control access to a file: By looking at permission and ownership, and executing the program either as the user that has access permission, or as member of the group that has access permission.

However, as at least on my system,

```
$ ll /dev/console
crw------- 1 root root 5, 1 Nov 29 06:59 /dev/console
```

the permissions to `/dev/console` are restricted to root only (probably for good reasons), so you either need to run it as root, or modify the `udev` rules to create `/dev/console` with a different group, and then run the program as member of this group (with the setgid bit, or otherwise).

But there's a better way to access the PC speaker (which is little known): The speaker shows up as an input-event device, and by writing to it in the correct format, you can directly control the speaker (including frequency). The system independent symlink for that is

```
/dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr
```

and if you follow the symlink, you should see something similar to

```
$ ll /dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 9 Nov 29 06:57 /dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr -> ../event5
$ ll /dev/input/event5
crw-rw---- 1 root input 13, 69 Nov 29 06:57 /dev/input/event5
```

So any member of the `input` group can write to this device, which is safer than running it as `root`.

The format of the events used by the input system is described in `/usr/src/linux/Documentation/input/input.txt` and the include files. It boils down to

```
struct input_event {
    struct timeval time;
    unsigned short type;
    unsigned short code;
    unsigned int value;
}
```

with a type of `EV_SND` ("sound"), that is, `0x12`. Just write such a struct to the file. You don't even need C for this, perl from the commandline will do, e.g.:

```
perl -e 'print pack("qssl", 0, 0x12, 2, 2000)' > /dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr
```

and to turn the beep off

```
perl -e 'print pack("qssl", 0, 0x12, 2, 0)' > /dev/input/by-path/platform-pcspkr-event-spkr
```

Comment: I appreciate your explanation on how the permission works, as well as the detailed solution explaining `pcspkr` as input-device mechanism. I implemented the second approach as it is the superior one.

Answer (score 3):

As long as your comfortable with the security implications, you can use the 'setuid' flag to allow users to run your executable as root.

First change ownership of the executable to root user and group.

```
# chown root:root /path/to/your_executable
```

Then enable its setuid flag.

```
# chmod u+s /path/to/your_executable
```

Now when any user runs your executable, the 'effective user' will be root, permitting access to your /dev/console.

You can confirm the setuid flag by examining the output of:

```
$ ls -l /path/to/your_executable
```

The output should be something like:

```
-rwsr-xr-x
```

Notice the 's' in the first octet.

Comment: @DRSDavidSoft did you find any of the answers helpful?

Comment: Yes – I did find both of the solutions here useful! The `setuid` flag in fact was used temporarily until I implemented @dirkt's answer.